# 400 Bad request with json object of curl POST command while flask is running

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, curl

I just made flask API. OS is Win10.  python version is 3.9.13. While the flask is running, I sent the following command.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/detect -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"filename": "xxx.jpg"}'
```

However, I received 400 BAD Request.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)</p>
```

The codes of python have not received the request.
I googled a lot.  Also, I checked the curl commands.

There is api directly.

```
---name of python= ___init___.py

from api import flask_test

from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request
api = Blueprint("api", __name__)


@api.get("/")
def index():
return jsonify({"column": "value"}), 201


@api.post("/detect")
def detection():
return flask_test.detection(request)
```

The next file is follows;

```
---name of python flask_test.py
def load_image(request):
    print('----')
    filename = request.json["filename"]
    print(filename)
    dir_image = str(basedir / "data" / "original" / filename)
    image = Image.open(dir_image).convert('RGB')
    return image, filename


def detection(request):
    print("test")
    load_image(request)
```

Running flask codes are as follows;

```
----app.py
import os
from flask import Flask

from api import api


class Config:
    TESTING = False
    DEBUG = False
    LABELS = [
        "people",
        "Population"
    ]


class LocalConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    DEBUG = True


config = {
    "base": Config,
    "local": LocalConfig,
}

config_name = os.environ.get("CONFIG", "local")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

app.register_blueprint(api)
```

At api directory, you need the following commands(Win10)

```
$FLASK_APP="app.py"
$FLASK_ENV="development" 
flask run
```

You will see json file at pot 5000.
{
"column": "value"
}

You see the following terminal screen;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpAtd.png)

Yuu see the following console screen;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztSgH.png)

You see "test", "----".  But, you can't see the result of print(filename)

So that, `request.json["filename"]`
doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning a non-json response.
try this:-

```
@api.post("/detect")
def detection():
return jsonify({"response":flask_test.detection(request)})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  But, http://127.0.0.1:5000/detect 
responded
Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
console screen showed
 "GET /detect HTTP/1.1" 405 -

Comment: change decorator to @api.post("/detect", methods=('GET'))